# textarea to list

Tags: python, textarea

textarea returns this

```
[u'a\r\nb\r\nc\r\nd\r\ne']
```

what is the best way to turn that into a list

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I paste a few things I tried here http://pastebin.com/fErU5arU (it expires in 10 minutes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> L = [u'a\r\nb\r\nc\r\nd\r\ne']
>>> L[0].split('\r\n')
[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtarea = "Thank you for the music\nWelcome to the jungle"
x = txtarea.splitlines()
print(x)
```